# How to fetch current subversion revision number and URL with maven

Tags: svn, maven-2, versioning

I make a checkout of some branch or tag from subversion repository and then build the project with maven.

Now, I'd like to get store *current* revision number and URL to some file. How can I do that? That is, I'd like to get revision number and URL of whatever branch/tag I have made checkout of.

I know about [buildnumber-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/) but I think it doesn't do this. It fetches revision number of branch that is specified in pom.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution exposed by user2990242 is great for standalone (thank you for good explanation).
After that, you just have to add information in the manifest.mf with maven-jar plugin (or maven-war).
here a full example:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>create</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <timestampFormat>{0,date,dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss}</timestampFormat>
                <doCheck>false</doCheck>
                <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
                <providerImplementations>
                    <svn>javasvn</svn>
                </providerImplementations>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.code.maven-scm-provider-svnjava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-svnjava</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.tmatesoft.svnkit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>svnkit</artifactId>
                    <version>1.8.5</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Implementation-Build>${buildNumber}</Implementation-Build>
                        <Implementation-Title>${project.name}</Implementation-Title>
                        <Implementation-Vendor>ENTERPRISE</Implementation-Vendor>
                        <Implementation-Version>${project.version}</Implementation-Version>
                        <Built-By>${user.name}</Built-By>
                        <Built-OS>${os.name}</Built-OS>
                        <Build-Date>${timestamp}</Build-Date>
                        <SCM-Revision>${buildNumber}</SCM-Revision>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [maven-antrun-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) to execute [svnversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svnversion.html).

```
<project>
  […]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
              <tasks>
                <exec executable="sh">
                  <arg value="-c"/>
                  <arg value="svnversion &gt;version.txt" />
                </exec>
              </tasks>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  […]
</project>
```

NB: I've used `sh -c` to run svnversion, so I can redirect the output to a file.  I don't *think* that you can get the output into a property for use by the maven build.

You can use the same approach to run `svn info --url`.

Comment: I ended up using this approach. However I am calling svn binary directly, this way it should work with both on linux and windows.

Comment: As for *I don't think that you can get the output into a property for use by the maven build:* `<exec outputproperty="my.revision" executable="svnversion">` does the trick for me. But: your answer fits the question, which asks for storing it in a file. Alternatively, one could use `${my.revision}` in some `src/main/resources/my.properties` file though, and use `<resources>...<filter>true</filter></resources>` to replace those placeholders while building.

Answer (score 4):

As said already the [Maven Build Number Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/) can be used to find the revision.

As for the URL:  Maven Practice is to put it in the [POM](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#SCM) using the <scm>-tag. If you configure this right once and then use the appriopriate Maven plugins ([maven-scm-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/scm/plugins/), [maven-release-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/)) for branching, tagging, releasing, etc. you can be sure the <scm>-tag always contains the right url.

Comment: This requires that I put the svn URL that I am checkouting to pom.xml. That does not work for me. I am not making checkout with maven, and sometime I checkout trunk, sometimes branchX, sometimes branchY. I'd like to fetch version data from checkouted svn tree.

Comment: If you can live with Dominics solution that's perfectly fine, but there's a good reason Maven folks decided to put the <scm>-tag in the POM. You might get the sources another way than as an SVN checkout (maybe you use 'svn export' or you use a zipped source-file or something else). BTW, checking out different branches is no problem, because if you use 'mvn release:branch' to create them, the POMs will have the correct value in the <scm>-tag.

Comment: Maybe I'll have to reconsider this, if we ever end up using maven to create branches. Currently we are doing it directly via svn. There also seemed to be some issues with build-number-plugin and parent/child pom.xmls.

Answer (score 1):

buildnumber-maven-plugin injects only current revision in your build so you're right. In order to get the URL I think that you should write a maven plugin that uses [SVNKit](http://svnkit.com/).

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the API only supports execution of the 'svn' command and it's various parameters and switches. The problem is that in subversion, a different executable command is used to retrieve a proper detailed version number, that being 'svnversion'.  Using this command, I can tell if I have a mixed version, a modified version, etc.  For example:

```
[jim@localhost sb_rc1 993]$ svn info | grep Revision
Revision: 51159
[jim@localhost sb_rc1 994]$ svnversion
51159M
[jim@localhost sb_rc1 994]$
```

Guess what? 'svn info' is lying to me here. My local copy is modified from the original 51159 which is why 'svnversion' reports the version number with an M attached to it. What if I'm experimenting with a branch that contains a mixed version? 'svnversion' can handle this. 'svn info' cannot. Worse, as shown above, it will provide misleading and potentially disastrous information if, for example, I'm basing a release off of the bad info.

Answer (score 0):

You've already said this doesn't meet your needs, but for others who have a similar problem it is worth noting that you can use the [Maven SCM API](http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-api/index.html) to invoke arbitrary SCM commands against the repository configured in the `scm` section of your POM. For example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130365/maven-commit-single-artifact-to-svn-repository/1131279#1131279) I showed how to commit a single file in a Maven mojo.

You could modify that example slightly to instead downcast the `SCMProvider` to `SvnExeScmProvider` and invoke its `info()` method. This returns an `SvnInfoScmResult` which wraps a `SvnInfoItem`. The item encapsulates the results of running an `svn info` command via the standard Subversion API.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, antrun supports exporting ant properties to mvn since version 1.7. See [Add a new parameter to export Ant properties to Maven properties](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MANTRUN-158)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but the `buildnumber-maven-plugin` now exposes an `${scmBranch}` value with the SCM URL in it. I've briefly tried it and it seems to work. To use it in resource filtering, you'll have to put it into a property first, as with the `timestamp` value exposed by Maven.

See http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/usage.html for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Buildernumber-maven-plugin dependents on the svn client you installed when "providerImplementations" not spepcified in the plugin configuration. When the svn execution path is not defined in the system path, or your svn client version is not matched, the plugin cannot call svn command line correctly.

So, adding a javasvn client and its dependency is a good idea.

```
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>create</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <doCheck>false</doCheck>
                <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
                <providerImplementations>
                  <svn>javasvn</svn>
                </providerImplementations>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.code.maven-scm-provider-svnjava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-svnjava</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.tmatesoft.svnkit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>svnkit</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7.8</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```