# Is there any free online maven repository?

Tags: maven-2, maven-3, repository

Is there any free online private maven2 or maven3 repository? So that team can access the repository from various region.

Comment: If it is available I don't want to setup my own maven repository(Sonatype) internally.

Comment: You want to upload internal artifacts to a FREE online repository?

Comment: He wrote: online **private** maven2 or maven3 repository

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you use github, you could use a private github project as your maven repository.  There are instruction on how to publish your maven artifacts to github here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14013645/82156

Comment: Version control is not recommended for this.

Comment: as of 2020, this is not a solution anymore.

Comment: as @JohnJohnPichler said, version control is not recommended for it, as you are going to run after 2 ways of versionning stuffs

Answer (score 11):

we can use dropbox for online maven repository. But it is not completely private. you can use it if it gives you enough privacy.

This is the instruction to create free maven online maven repository on dropbox

1. Create an account on dropbox
2. Download and install dropbox client
3. After you install dropbox client, A folder called "Dropbox" will create in Users folder. There is a public folder in it. Create a sub folder in public folder and copy the url of that sub folder(ex: C:\Users\Lakshman\Dropbox\Public\repository)
4. Execute the following command to deploy the project artifacts to this path

`mvn deploy -DskipTests=true -DaltDeploymentRepository=dropbox::default::file:///C:/Users/Lakshman/Dropbox/Public/repository`

5. you can use this in your pom file to the above task

   ```
    <distributionManagement>
       <repository>
       <id>dropbox.repo</id>
        <url>file:///C:/Users/Lakshman/Dropbox/Public/repository</url>
       </repository>
   </distributionManagement>
   ```

if you have sync your local folder with dropbox it will automatically upload artifacts to online repository. you can get the link by login to Dropbox and go to public folder and click `copy public link`.

This solution got from [here](http://ediweissmann.com/blog/2013/07/11/free-private-maven-repository-hosting/) and referenced [this](https://code.google.com/p/peter-lavalle/wiki/MavenOnDropBox) also.

Answer (score 9):

We use  https://repsy.io in one of our project. It's straight simple and convenient with 1GB free limit.

Answer (score 8):

I just found a free repo for personal projects. Might not be suitable for team work and/or professional use though. Note that it seems to be from Russia. I am not connected in any kind to that project so I have no idea about the privacy of the data posted there. But it seems to work ok.

https://mymavenrepo.com

I have not tried but there is also

https://bintray.com/

This one might have a better reputation :)

Comment: It's only a free beta. They will charge fees in the future. They only say, they will keep it affordable. Also mymavenrepo is not really secure. You get a public read/write URL and the only security meassurement is that it's hard to guess the URL.

Comment: I don't know bintray, but I'll check it out, thanks.

Comment: Bintray is not free

Comment: Bintray is about to be closed at May 1st 2021: https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter

Comment: https://mymavenrepo.com works fine, and gives 256 Mb for free

Answer (score 6):

Update: GitHub launches the Package feature in Beta which supports the Maven: https://github.com/features/package-registry

Update: the Deveo has been acquired by Perforce, see [this link](https://www.perforce.com/deveo-customer-info)

> As of September 12, Deveo is now Helix TeamHub. The new name and branding represent our new, integrated solution from Deveo and Perforce.
>
> Helix TeamHub can be hosted in our cloud or on your own servers with Helix TeamHub Enterprise, powered by Helix4Git.

Have you tried [Deveo](http://blog.deveo.com/whats-new-in-deveo-3-17/), I am using this cloud service and has 1G storage for free. You can deploy the Maven repository on it.

> New features in Deveo 3.17
>
> Pull requests between repositories
>
> **Maven and Ivy repositories**
>
> Deadlines for issues
>
> Emojis

[image]

Comment: As I can see, it now called [HelixTeadHub](http://info.perforce.com/try-perforce-helix-teamhub-free)

Comment: @guai you are right, they are acquired by Perforce https://www.perforce.com/deveo-customer-info at last year (September 12)

Answer (score 5):

I recently wrote a lightweight Google App-Engine application to host my private repositories, backed by Google Cloud Storage (which is [multi-regional per default](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/storage-classes#multi-regional)):

https://github.com/renaudcerrato/appengine-maven-repository

Thanks to Google App-Engine [free quotas](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas), and depending on the scale needed, you won't have to pay anything.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you could use a SVN repository. Some of them are available for private usage for free. Take a look on [Maven: Commit single artifact to svn repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130365/maven-commit-single-artifact-to-svn-repository)

Comment: For newcomers: this answer is ten years old, and is no longer a relevant answer in 2021.